# What will be the new state after the outcome of the measurement of the state of the first qubit as ǀ0>?

Tags: mathematics

Two qubits are prepared in a superposition state of the form:
[image: qubits state]
What will be the new state after the outcome of the measurement of the state of the first qubit as
ǀ0>?

Comment: Welcome to quantum computing stack exchange. Just as a tip its preferred if equations are formatted with LaTeX instead of using images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is asking about the post measurement state of the system $|\psi \rangle_{post}$.

You can work this out is as follows.

We know that the first qubit is measured to be $|0 \rangle$ so we know that our system can only be some superposition of the $|01 \rangle$ the $|00 \rangle$ states. This means we can rule out the states $|10 \rangle$ and $|11\rangle$.

The sum of the squares of our amplitudes must always equal 1 as the amplitudes relate to probablities. so we have can divide through by a  normalising factor $N$ to ensure that the post measurement state is normalised.

\begin{equation}
|\psi \rangle_{post} = \frac{1}{N} \big(|00\rangle +  |01\rangle\big)
\end{equation}

I’ve absorbed the factors of $\frac{1}{2}$ into the definition of $N$ here.

We must have that $2* (\frac{1}{N})^2 = 1  \implies N= \sqrt{2}$

So our normalised post measurement state is the following

\begin{equation}
|\psi \rangle_{post} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \big(|00\rangle +  |01\rangle\big)
\end{equation}